# How to copy excel data into multiple notepad file by vba

Tags: excel, vba, notepad

I have 4 column in my excel data, this is location wise data (Column-A) but I want location wise filter and only Barcode would copy and it has to paste in to notepad there is not limit of bar-codes and it should save in particular location. and it should rename with File Rename Column (Column-B).

**Here I am attaching file...**

Location wise Data

[image: 1]

Output Text File - Result

[image: 2]

```
A               B            C          D
LocationName FileRename Barcode Qty
Box-01  Box-01 108  8905425661077   1
Box-01  Box-01 108  8905425723577   1
Box-01  Box-01 108  8905425652105   1
Box-01  Box-01 108  8905425652969   1
Box-01  Box-01 108  8905425654659   1
Box-01  Box-01 108  8905425654222   1
Box-01  Box-01 108  8905425367504   1
Box-02  Box-02 35   8905425192250   1
Box-02  Box-02 35   8905425190454   1
Box-02  Box-02 35   8905425191475   1
Box-02  Box-02 35   8905425366668   1
Box-02  Box-02 35   8905425204106   1
Box-02  Box-02 35   8905425191819   1
Box-03  Box-03 56   8905425650231   1
Box-03  Box-03 56   8905425652235   1
Box-03  Box-03 56   8905425723133   1
Box-03  Box-03 56   8905425723898   1
Box-03  Box-03 56   8905425650231   1
Box-03  Box-03 56   8905425650156   1
Box-03  Box-03 56   8905425923793   1
Box-03  Box-03 56   8905425652013   1
```

Thanks & Regards.
7011675525

Comment: What have you tried to far? What is your specific issue? Your requirement can be splittet into the tasks **(o)** Filter data  **(o)** Write filtered data into a text file **(o)** Name the file correctly. Where have you problems? Note that SO is not a free coding service, we are here to help programmers when they are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sort source table by the 2nd col before exporting

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Sort method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Open statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/open-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim rngData As Range, i As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Dim arrData, sPath As String, FileNumber As Long
    Const KEY_COL = 2
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Modify as needed
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    With oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        ' Sort data
        .Sort Key1:=.Columns(KEY_COL), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        Set rngData = .Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    ' Load data into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 2) = arrData(i - 1, 2) Then
            ' Write to txt file
            Print #FileNumber, arrData(i, 3)
        Else
            If FileNumber > 0 Then Close FileNumber
            If Len(arrData(i, 2)) = 0 Then Exit For
            FileNumber = FreeFile
            ' Create a new file
            Open sPath & arrData(i, 2) & ".txt" For Output As FileNumber
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

---

Update:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim rngData As Range, i As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Dim arrData, sPath As String, FileNumber As Long
    Const KEY_COL = 2
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Modify as needed
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    With oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        ' Sort data
        .Sort Key1:=.Columns(KEY_COL), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        Set rngData = .Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    ' Load data into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If Not arrData(i, 2) = arrData(i - 1, 2) Then
            If FileNumber > 0 Then Close FileNumber
            If Len(arrData(i, 2)) = 0 Then Exit For
            FileNumber = FreeFile
            ' Create a new file
            Open sPath & arrData(i, 2) & ".txt" For Output As FileNumber
        End If
        Print #FileNumber, Trim(arrData(i, 3))
    Next i
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code but there is some error at the time of running. if you run this code, files are saving with Correct Rename but in the text files there is space in all output text files before and after the Bar-codes. and correct date is not coping as per the location wise. it's taking one barcode less as per the data.

Comment: I've revised the code for other two issues. The extra spaces are from your data table. `correct date is not coping` What's the correct date?

Comment: issue has been resolved -- Thanks You so much  !!